# Is there a graphic showing where we can and cannot get to utilizing only a compass and straightedge?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, geometric-construction

I know that we cannot get to the measurement of pi units utilizing a compass and straightedge. I was wondering if there is a graphic that shows points all points that can or cannot be found utilizing standard compass and straightedge techniques.

I also know the points we can get are infinite, the graphic I am thinking of would be a gradient of pure black being one one ¨movement¨ two ¨movements¨ being slightly faded towards white and so on. I think this would make a very interesting picture.

Comment: The allowed operations are + - x / $\sqrt$. Any constructible number is formed by those operations on natural numbers.

Comment: @Joe Have you tried drawing this picture? How far did you get?

Comment: So something along the lines of [this image](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#/media/File%3AAlgebraicszoom.png) but for constructible rather than algebraic numbers? Note that it is impossible to tell just from the image that $\pi$ is not algebraic.

Comment: no, I haven´t, being that a number of points that can be created with each movement grow exponentially I thought it would be best left to a computer. I don't have the wherewithal to program this.

Comment: Rahul, I believe that is what I am looking for! Thanks

Comment: Joe, no, this has come up before. The constructible points in the plane resemble the set of points with both coordinates rational. The result is a sort of fog, everywhere dense. That picture is something else